# Jetty Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception on ISO-8859 Request with Spring

Tags: encoding, jetty

A Remote Service calls our Jetty Server with a Request encoded in ISO-8859-15. This special request is mapped on a Spring Controller. Jetty is not able to encode the request in right manner and shows the following exception:

```
exception=org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte F6 in state 3}
org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte F6 in state 3
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable.appendByte(Utf8Appendable.java:168) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable.append(Utf8Appendable.java:93) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoded.decodeUtf8To(UrlEncoded.java:506) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoded.decodeTo(UrlEncoded.java:554) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractParameters(Request.java:285) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameter(Request.java:695) ~[na:na]
    ....
```

---

**Solution**

In Spring it's possible to force an encoding of the request through a CharacterEncodingFilter even if the whole application speaks UTF-8. The Exception should disappear.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>ISO-8859-15</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/specialRequest.do</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

If this is not working for you

- find out the remote system encoding
- start Wireshark to analyze incoming package through ip.src == xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  filter
- search the requests body for special characters (recalculate the hex value to binary and try several frequently used encodings to find exactly the one who is matched the exception)
- set encoding through Jetty's start.ini ie. with the following parameters

  Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.URI.charset=ISO-8859-15

  Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoding.charset=ISO-8859-15

Otherwise drop me a message if you have more questions.

Comment: What version were you running before? If it was an earlier version of 8.0 then we can have a look at the changes in those versions and see if something pops up.

Comment: It was jetty-7.4.2.v20110526. But I am not 100% sure that this error is a Jetty thing. I will test it today (same case) with jetty7 version again. I am on my way...

Comment: Hmm, with Jetty7 I get a IllegalArgumentException: !utf8 on org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable.appendByte(Utf8Appendable.java:130). Looks like the same but with other words. Seems like it is a new issue that comes from "outside" and is independent from my migration. I hate those problems when you changing to something new  and a in the same moment something else will pop up.

Comment: Seems like 0xF6 is character "ö" in ISO-8859-1. But what means state 3?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the client is sending text that should be encoded as UTF8, but isn't encoding it.

In order to properly diagnose this issue you'll need to understand UTF8 (which you might do, I don't know)

In UTF8 any character with an encoding of 127 (0x7F) or less - *i.e.* only the lowest 7 bit  are used - is included in the stream *as is* (no special encoding). But anything greater than 127 (i.e. at least one bit higher than the 7th is set), is specially encoded.

`0xF6` is greater than `0x7F` so if a client wants to send that character, it should encoded it.

`0xF6` in binary is `11110110`, which in UTF8 should be `11000011 10110110` (`C3 B6`)

So, if the client wants to send the ISO8859-1 character of 0xF6, then it should be sending the UTF8 byte sequence of 0xC3 0xB6.

You really need to work out what the client wants to be sending, what charset/encoding that data is in, and why it's not converting it to valid UTF8 before it sends it.

*( "state 3", is to do with Jetty's internal tables for doing UTF8 decoding, it's not really very helpful for diagnosing this problem. It will only come in handy if you find the client, and it looks like the client is doing the right thing, and you suspect that Jetty's UTF8 decoding is wrong)*

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer! Now I get the point about the meaning of the state. I will check the incoming request's encoding today and for sure you are right.

Comment: But if they send ISO encoded Request, how to tell Jetty to use ISO encoding and not UTF-8?

Comment: Ok seems like the provider that called our server has only ISO-8859 encoding ;) So Tim, it's not directly the answer but I up-voted your post because it pointed me into the right direction.