# Jetty does not recognise 'POST' method calls for some requests

Tags: http, jetty, jetty-9

EC2 Linux server running Jetty 9.3.0 on Java 8 fails to recognise some POSTS requests.

It looks as these requests are malformed, but it started when we switch EC2 machine, the code hasn't changed and it wasn't happening before.

I've verified with the request log that request is indeed a POST request.

This is the log output -

```
2015-10-31 12:15:55.700:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte 8b in state 0
2015-10-31 12:15:55.700:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte 5d in state 5
2015-10-31 12:15:55.700:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte 0a in state 2
2015-10-31 12:15:55.700:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte 35 in state 2
2015-10-31 12:15:55.700:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte A4 in state 0
2015-10-31 12:15:55.700:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte 90 in state 0
2015-10-31 12:15:55.700:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte 44 in state 2
2015-10-31 12:15:55.700:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte 90 in state 0
2015-10-31 12:15:55.701:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte 88 in state 0
2015-10-31 12:15:55.701:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte A8 in state 0
2015-10-31 12:15:55.701:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte 92 in state 0
2015-10-31 12:15:55.701:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte C1 in state 0
2015-10-31 12:15:55.701:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte 88 in state 0
2015-10-31 12:15:55.701:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte F6 in state 0
2015-10-31 12:15:55.701:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte 0b in state 2
2015-10-31 12:15:55.701:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte F6 in state 0
2015-10-31 12:15:55.701:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte 82 in state 0
2015-10-31 12:15:55.701:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte B1 in state 0
2015-10-31 12:15:55.701:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte Ea in state 3
2015-10-31 12:15:55.701:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte 6f in state 2
2015-10-31 12:15:55.701:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte 04 in state 2
2015-10-31 12:15:55.701:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte Ee in state 3
2015-10-31 12:15:55.701:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte Fb in state 0
2015-10-31 12:15:55.702:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte F7 in state 0
2015-10-31 12:15:55.702:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte F7 in state 2
2015-10-31 12:15:55.702:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte Fb in state 3
2015-10-31 12:15:55.702:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte Cc in state 3
2015-10-31 12:15:55.702:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte Be in state 0
2015-10-31 12:15:55.702:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte 00 in state 2
2015-10-31 12:15:55.702:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte A2 in state 0
2015-10-31 12:15:55.702:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte F8 in state 0
2015-10-31 12:15:55.702:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte A9 in state 0
2015-10-31 12:15:55.702:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte 6c in state 2
2015-10-31 12:15:55.702:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte A6 in state 0
2015-10-31 12:15:55.702:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte 86 in state 0
2015-10-31 12:15:55.702:WARN:oeju.UrlEncoded:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte 8c in state 0
2015-10-31 12:15:55.702:WARN:oeju.Utf8Appendable:qtp1588970020-251: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! incomplete UTF8 sequence
2015-10-31 12:15:55 qtp1588970020-251 PageNotFound [WARN] Request method 'POST' not supported
2015-10-31 12:15:55 qtp1588970020-251 DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver [WARN] Handling of [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException] resulted in Exception
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.reset(HttpConnection.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.access$300(HttpConnection.java:576)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:510)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:596)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:650)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:172)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:158)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:436)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ByteArrayISO8859Writer.writeTo(ByteArrayISO8859Writer.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler.handle(ErrorHandler.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:572)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:203)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveException(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:111)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1183)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1020)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:816)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1121)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1055)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:199)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.error(Dispatcher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler.handle(ErrorHandler.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:572)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:158)
        at net.bull.javamelody.FilterServletResponseWrapper.sendError(FilterServletResponseWrapper.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.handleMissingServletRequestParameter(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:265)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveException(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:123)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1183)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1020)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:816)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1684)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:165)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:45)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
        at com.example.commons.security.SecurityFilter.forwardRequest(SecurityFilter.java:78)
        at com.example.commons.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:208)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:181)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1121)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1055)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:515)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:291)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:238)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:192)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:238)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:57)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-10-31 12:15:55.714:WARN:oejsh.ErrorHandler:qtp1588970020-251: EXCEPTION
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:203)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:349)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:296)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:299)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1120)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:932)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:816)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1121)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1055)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:199)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.error(Dispatcher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler.handle(ErrorHandler.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:572)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:158)
        at net.bull.javamelody.FilterServletResponseWrapper.sendError(FilterServletResponseWrapper.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.handleMissingServletRequestParameter(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:265)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveException(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:123)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1183)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1020)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:816)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1684)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:165)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:45)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
        at com.example.commons.security.SecurityFilter.forwardRequest(SecurityFilter.java:78)
        at com.example.commons.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:208)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:181)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1121)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1055)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:515)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:291)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:238)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:192)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:238)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:57)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-10-31 12:15:55.716:WARN:oejh.HttpParser:qtp1588970020-251: parse exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: too much data seeking EOF in CLOSE for HttpChannelOverHttp@2a0ff69e{r=1,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=-}
```

Any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: Is the request data UTF-8?  That's what Jetty is expecting here but the data it's receiving is not valid UTF-8.

Comment: Try these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136557/jetty-utf8appendablenotutf8exception-on-iso-8859-request-with-spring http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437819/illegalargumentexception-utf8-jetty-error-on-most-requests

Comment: Can you capture the request headers and (some of) the request body content for the question?

Comment: Yes, I've captured it - but it's encrypted due to the use of TLS 1.2, it doesn't reproduce locally.